# (node:3340) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting this error? And it's really annoying here's my code

```
else if(query === "collection") {
                  const blacklistedWords = useridWords.get(message.guild.id);
                  if(blacklistedWords) 
                  return message.channel.send(blacklistedWords, { 
                      code: "js",
                  });
```

this is the line of where the error is....

Comment: It means that `useridWords` is empty. Please post more details about your code. We could not tell why `useridWords` may be empty

Comment: ok i will post all of my code